# C - Big-endian struct interconvert with little-endian struct

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, struct

I have two structs which have the same data members. (one is a *big_endian* struct, the other is *little_endian* ) now I have to interconvert with them. But when I code, I found that there are lots of repeated codes with little change. How can I change these codes to be more elegant without **repeated code**? (repeated code means these code may be similar such as `mode == 1` and `mode == 2`, which only differ in assignment position. It doesn't look elegant but works.)

here is my code:

```
#pragma scalar_storage_order big-endian

typedef struct {   
    int a1;    
    short a2;    
    char a3;    
    int a4;    
} test_B;

#pragma scalar_storage_order default

typedef struct {
    int a1;    
    short a2;    
    char a3;    
    int a4;    
} test_L;


void interconvert(test_L *little, test_B *big, int mode) {
    // if mode == 1 , convert little to big    
    // if mode == 2 , convert big to little    
    // it may be difficult and redundant when the struct has lots of data member!    
    if(mode == 1) {
        big->a1 = little->a1;
        big->a2 = little->a2;
        big->a3 = little->a3;
        big->a4 = little->a4;
    }
    else if(mode == 2) {
        little->a1 = big->a1;
        little->a2 = big->a2;
        little->a3 = big->a3;
        little->a4 = big->a4;
    }
    else return;
}
```

---

<sub>Note：The above code must run on **gcc-7 or higher** ，because of the `#pragma scalar_storage_order`</sub>

Comment: I don't see any problem with this. Maybe you could create a separate functions `little_to_big(test_L *little, test_B *big)` and `big_to_little(test_B *big, test_L *little)`. I often have classes that have more than 4 fields and there is no other way to assign/initialize them. As a side note if you have name of your function consisting of several words, devide them using snake or camel case.

Comment: You're using bizarre characters in this question such as `？` and `。` ... this is a little thing, but if you could fix it I think the problem would be a bit easier to read.  Also, maybe I'm missing something obvious, but what do you mean here by "repeat codes"?  Thanks, and welcome to SO!

Comment: “repeat code” means these code may be similar such as mode==1 & mode==2 ，which only different in assignment postion。It does‘t looks elegent  but works

Comment: Have you looked at [Wikipedia - Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) -- that also provides a C-function for converting integer values between the big/little endian? (you can trivially adapt for `short` values and for `char` nothing is required.)

Comment: Thank. But htonl doesn't work in my case. @ David C. Rankin

Comment: There is a fundamental underlying error in this question: trying to use structures to describe binary data formats in a portable manner.  Instead, you should write pack/unpack functions to convert between binary data buffers and internal, native format data (that does not need to resemble the binary data storage at all).  Yes, I know that many people do do that. My point is that it is nonportable, and hard to maintain; and an easy source of bugs. Do you *want to* write buggy code, or code you can trust?

Comment: I have roughly know what  do you mean. However, can you give me a little example to make the question clear. Thanks.

Comment: Your approach is begging for bugs.  The *only* time you should ever care about endianness is when you need to read from or write to an external source of data (e.g. file on disk, network socket), and even then you should convert between a known endianness (mandated by the external format) and the system's endianness (which C abstracts away, so you shouldn't even care what that is).

Comment: @jamesdlin Not exactly.  I want to find a more elegant way to code. I used the "C compiler" calls the struct  data member to interconvert. In this way , I did not care about the endianness. But it is not elegant .

Answer (score -1):

An answer was posted which suggested to use memcpy for this problem, but that answer has been deleted. Actually that answer was right, if used correctly, and I want to explain why.

The #pragma specified by the OP is central, as he notes out:

> Note: the above code must run on gcc-7 or higher because of the #pragma scalar_storage_order

The struct from the OP:

```
#pragma scalar_storage_order big-endian
typedef struct {   
    int a1;    
    short a2;    
    char a3;    
    int a4;    
} test_B;
```

means that the instruction "test_B.a2=256" writes, in the two consecutive bytes belonging to the a2 member, respectively 1 and 0. This is big-endian. The similar instruction "test_L.a2=256" would instead strore the bytes 0 and 1 (little endian).

The following memcpy:

```
memcpy(&test_L, &test_B, sizeof test_L)
```

would make the bytes for test_L.a2 equal to 1 and 0, because that is the ram content of test_B.a2. But now, reading test_L.a2 in little endian mode, those two bytes mean 1. We wrote 256 and read back 1. This is exactly the wanted conversion.

To use correctly this mechanism, it is sufficient to write in one struct, memcpy() in the other, and read the other - member by member. What was big-endian becomes little-endian and viceversa. Of course, if the intention is to elaborate data and apply calculations on it, it is important to know what endianness has the data; if it matches the default mode, no transformation has to be done before the calculations, but the transformation has to be applied later. On the contrary, if the incoming data does not match the "default endianness" of the processor, it must be transformed first.

---

EDIT
After the comment of the OP, below, I investigated more. I took a look at this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Layout-Pragmas.html

Well, there are three #pragma available to choose the byte layout: *big-endian*, *little-endian*, and **default**. One of the first two is equal to the last: if the target machine is little-endian, default means little-endian; if it is big-endian, default means big-endian. This is more than logical.

So, doing a memcpy() between big-endian and default does nothing on a big-endian machine; and also this is logical. Ok, better I stress more that memcpy() does absolutely nothing per se: it only moves data from a ram area treated in a certain manner to another area treated in another manner. The two different areas are treated differently only when a normal member access is done: here come to play the **#pragma scalar_storage_order**. And as I written before, it is important to know what endiannes have the data entering the program. If they come from TCP network, for example, we know that is big-endian; more in general, if it is taken from outside the "program" and respect a protocol, we should know what endianness has.

To convert from an endianness to the other, one should use **little** and **big**, *NOT* default, because that *default* is surely equal to one of the former two.

---

### Still another edit

Stimulated by comments, and by Jamesdlin who used an online compiler, I tried to do it too. At this url  http://tpcg.io/lLe5EW 
there is the demonstration that assigning to a member of one struct, memcpy to another, and reading that, the endian conversion is done. That's all.

Comment: Sorry to tell you that the memcpy function runs exactly what we want on Mac OS with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5). But neither on ubuntu(gcc-7) nor on Mac OS(gcc-7).

Comment: @b.bkb The fact that memcpy works at least in one case means that the idea is not totally wrong. Further analysis could tell what is wrong in the two other systems, but I must ask: where the data come from? And how are the data output after elaboration? What is the endianness of the various systems?

Comment: Sorry, but this (and your comments to the deleted answer) does not make sense.  `memcpy` takes a `void*` and a number of bytes to copy.  It knows *nothing* about what's being pointed to, whether it's a `struct`, what members that `struct` contains, etc.  What I *would* be willing to believe is that in some situations, a compiler might *optimize out* `memcpy` of `struct` pointers by inlining member-wise assignments.

Comment: But, of course, if that is the case, then it'd be a compiler bug because optimizations shouldn't change behavior.  I would be curious to know if the `memcpy` approach "works" with all optimizations disabled.

Comment: @jamesdlin The trick is not made by memcpy() at all: that function only has to copy blindly and verbatim a sequence of bytes, it is meant to do that. The trick is that the compiler treats differently two structures, thanks to the #pragmas that choose an endianness. It is similar to copy 4 bytes with memcpy, from an uint32 to an int32: after the copy, the int32 can be negative, even if the uint32 was (of course) not. The same bit pattern is interpreted differently... and in this case, with the two structs, is the same: same bit patterns mean different things.

Comment: No, sorry, that still makes no sense.  We accept that `memcpy` copies bytes blindly: it does a *byte-for-byte* copy from the source to the destination.  But you don't *want* a byte-for-byte copy; you want to reverse bytes for *each* `struct` member.  There is no way for `memcpy `to know how which bytes to reverse.  Yes,  `scalar_storage_order` controls how the `struct` members are stored in memory, but *only* when it knows that it's dealing with those `struct`s (which is why member-wise assignment works).  Once you've converted to `void*` then it no longer knows anything.

Comment: @jamesdlin I updated my post, hoping to be more clear. And I want to remind you that the OP tried to do memcpy(), and it worked (see comment above). If you were true, it shouldn't have worked, never. Instead it did. And I've been also clear about member access, and I also made an example on int32 and uint32 - I think that the last example should be very clear, could you explain what is wrong in that example?

Comment: Your analogy of `memcpy` with `uint32` and `int32` does not apply at all.  In that case, you *can* just blindly copy bytes.  In fact, you don't need to copy at all: you could just do: `*((int32*) &some_uint32)` to "reinterpret" the existing bytes without changing any of them.  In contrast, an endianness conversion requires changing the data (reversing bytes); the whole point of `scalar_storage_order` is to change how the `struct` is stored in memory.  If you still think `memcpy` should work, then do you also think that `*(test_L*) &big)` would work too?

Comment: I've already provided a hypothesis for why `memcpy` might *seem* to work.  That it seems to work with clang but not gcc supports my guess.

Comment: @jamesdlin my point is that the same bit pattern is intepreted differently by the type of access: int32 vs uint32. particular meaning. Your example typecast works, if you dereference a single member, because you are telling the compiler to treat big endian data as it was little endian, and the compiler will happily do it, the same as your previous cast on int32/uint32. If you do not refer to a member, then no endianness has meaning, like no signness exists if you don't refer integers.

Comment: Endianness conversion is not about interpreting bit patterns differently.  It's about reordering bytes.  If bytes are not reordered in memory, then `#pragma scalar_storage_order` isn't doing what it's supposed to.   I guess reasoning doesn't work, so here's evidence: https://godbolt.org/z/n8cSSj and https://godbolt.org/z/JF8J5g Notice how with gcc there's a call to `memcpy`, but clang instead inlined a bunch of member-wise copying itself?

Comment: @b.bkb Please retry, if you want, but using *big* and *little*, not *default*.

Comment: @jamesdlin you are demonstrating that memcpy() does nothing, and I agree. Try to assign a member, memcpy() to another struct, and print that member. And use big/little, not default. TY.

Comment: 1. Upon further investigation `clang -Wall` actually complains about not recognizing `scalar_storage_order`, and I find no documentation providing evidence that it is supported, so whatever claim that it worked with clang is highly suspect.

Comment: 2. Your example demonstrates that you've completely misunderstood what is desired.  The fact that printing `big.a1` and `little.a1` prints *different* values means that the bytes were blindly copied and that no reversal was performed.  That is *not* what the OP is asking for.  The whole point of doing member-wise copying is to preserve the *value*s while transforming the representation in-memory.

Comment: @jamesdlin may be you are true. It all depends on how the data is accessed after the transformation. But if clang does not transform, and the OP told it worked, then the mistery gets even more deep...

Comment: The OP clearly wants the equivalent of doing member-wise copies without having to manually enumerate all members.  Your approach does not do that.  I suspect that the OP might have initially *thought* that clang worked because clang doesn't warn by default and because the whole point is that the *values* should not visibly change; the only way to tell that they have different endianness would be to cast to `char*` and to inspect each byte.

Comment: @linuxfan  I have changed default to endian-little. And the result has no difference with 'default'  . As  I know , the default means the c default endianness  which is always endian-little.

Comment: @b.bkb All boils down on how you get the data in, and how you put the data out. If you are not really interested in the single members, then memcpy() is not for you because, as James says, the memory layout is not changed.

Comment: @b.bkb Endianness is not tied to the language.  It's tied to the target hardware architecture.  Almost all modern processors (x64, x86, ARM) are little-endian. (ARM actually supports a big-endian mode, but in practice nobody uses it.)

Comment: Thanks for your support and help. When I find a better way , I will tell you all.